# deleting an element in a linked list in c

Tags: c, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

This procedure in C should delete an element of the linked list according to it's data, but it gets stuck every time I call it. I can confirm that the problem is not with declaring the type of the list or something related.

```
void supprime(list *head, int data2) {//failed
//data2 refers to the value we are looking for
    list p= *head, k;
    if (*head== NULL) 
        printf("the list is empty");
    else {
        while ((p->data!= data2) && (!p)) {
            k= p;
            p= p->next;
        }
        if (p->data == data2) {
            k->next= p->next;
            free(p);
        }
        else 
            printf("This data is not available\n");
    }
}
```

If anyone wants the [entire source code](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkEail-kUdTklxY4S3QbE59j-A25), just to make sure that everything is okay.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Especially you need to show how you invoke `supprime`.

Comment: `while ((p->data!= data2) && (!p)) {` You should reverse those.

Comment: There are many other possibilities for problems, like dereferencing `k` uninitialized if deleting the first node.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes, if p is `NULL`, we need to check that first, before accessing `p->data`

Comment: Is the type `list` defined in a way that it can meaningfully be compared to NULL? `head` is a pointer to list, `*head` is a list, `*head == NULL`compares a list to NULL. Does not seem plausible. I would find `head==NULL` more convincing.

Comment: @Yunnosch OP says type of list is not the problem clearly in the question.

Comment: @aksha Even if list is free of problems, it is easy to misuse when using pointers to it.

Comment: Also, `if (p->data == data2) {`, you should check if `p` is `NULL` here.

Comment: @Hocine Abdellatif Why does the second parameter have name data2?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow He has mentioned in the comments below the function definition. -- data2 refers to the value we are looking for

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - did you see this line: `if (p->data == data2) {`, or are you just implying in general that `data2` is not a very descriptive name :)

Comment: `if (p->data == data2)` should simply be `if (p)` as only when p is not null has the data been found.

Comment: There is a problem when `(*head)->data==data2)` (i.e. the data searched is in the firts list item)

Comment: @ryyker Low-qualified programmers invent names like data3 and then invent reasons to use them. The parameter could be named just like data.

Comment: @akshayk07 And what? Why is the parameter named like data2?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Got your point now.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
int supprime( list *head, int data ) 
{
    while ( *head && ( *head )->data != data ) head = &( *head )->next;

    int success = *head != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        list tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
}
```

Take into account that the finction should not issue a message. It is the client of the function who decides whether to issue a message.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct cell 
{
    int data;
    struct cell *next;
} cellule;

typedef cellule *list;

void affiche_liste( list head ) 
{
    for ( ; head; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", head->data );
    }
}

int ajout_fin( list *head, int data ) 
{
    list tmp = malloc( sizeof( *tmp ) );
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = tmp;
    }

    return success; 
}

int supprime( list *head, int data ) 
{
    while ( *head && ( *head )->data != data ) head = &( *head )->next;

    int success = *head != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        list tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;
    list head = NULL;

    int i = 0;
    for ( ; i < N; i++ )
    {
        ajout_fin( &head, i );
        affiche_liste( head );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    while ( i )
    {
        supprime( &head, --i );
        affiche_liste( head );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 
0 1 
0
```